# Change responsive positioning of nested columns from vertical to horizontal using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-grid

I'm building a responsive page layout using Bootstrap 4 and want to modify the alignment of two nested columns based on the size of the browser window.

The project is a pricing page that displays a list of features below each of three options.

On larger screens (md, lg, xl) all three pricing plans are arranged in columns, and the features for each plan are displayed one-by-one below the plan info. For smaller screens (xs, xm) I'd like to split the feature list into two columns and have them show side-by-side.

I've looked around for solutions that support this use case but haven't been able to find anything just yet.

I'm attempting to solve this issue using vanilla Bootstrap 4 in an HTML document using the built-in breakpoints. I've attempted to solve this issue using flexbox in addition to standard sizing classes and so far nothing has worked. (Note that I'm still pretty new to flexbox.)

**NOTE:** The solution I'm looking for is related to the two columns displaying "feature 1", "feature 2," and so on. The encompassing plan columns are currently rendering properly, but the feature columns are not.

```
<!-- PRICING PLANS -->

<div class="bg-primary p-3 my-5">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Package 1 -->
    <div class="col-md h-100 bg-white p-3">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="mb-3 bg-success text-center">
          <p>Package 1</p>
          <p>$29.99</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-success">

        <!-- THIS IS MY CURRENT (NON-WORKING) SOLUTION: -->

          <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
            <p>feature 1</p>
            <p>feature 2</p>
            <p>feature 3</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
            <p>feature 4</p>
            <p>feature 5</p>
            <p>feature 6</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- REMAINDER OF CODE FOR DISPLAY PURPOSES ONLY -->

    <!-- Package 2 -->
    <div class="col-md h-md-100 mx-md-4 my-md-0 my-4 bg-white p-3">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="mb-3 bg-success text-center">
          <p>Package 2</p>
          <p>$19.99</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-success">
          <p>features</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Package 3 -->
    <div class="col-md h-md-100 bg-white p-3">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="mb-3 bg-success text-center">
          <p>Package 3</p>
          <p>$9.99</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-success">
          <p>features</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

I thought that by making the columns have a col-xs-6 property they would align horizontally up until hititng col-md-12 -- however they aren't showing up any differently regardless of window size.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want items in three columns on larger screens, and there to be two items side-by-side on smaller screens?

Comment: Ah - thanks for the clarifying question. I want the *features list* to show up as two side-by-side columns on a smaller screen, when the pricing plans are displayed in a vertical order. (The plan columns themselves are rerendering correctly.)

Comment: is `bg-success` a flex parent in your non-working? If it's not, add `display: flex` as an inline-style to test that.

Comment: @disinfor Yes, it's the parent div.

Comment: I meant, does `bg-sucess` have `display: flex` set as one of it's properties?

Comment: Just adding `d-flex` results in odd behavior. However, I added a second property that did the trick.

Comment: Notice: there are no `xs` and `xm` breaking points in Bootstrap. There are `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`.

Comment: @JakubMuda Bootstrap 4.3 defaults elements to `xs` if it's not otherwise specified. Hence, `"col-6 col-sm-3"` will create a col with a default (`xs`) grid sizing of `col-6`, which resizes at the `-sm` breakpoint of 576px. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because `bg-success` in your non-working example is not a flex parent (`display: flex`). In this example, I put an extra class on it that makes it a flex parent and you get the desired output.

```css
.make-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- PRICING PLANS -->

<div class="bg-primary p-3 my-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- Package 1 -->
      <div class="col-md h-100 bg-white p-3">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="mb-3 bg-success text-center">
            <p>Package 1</p>
            <p>$29.99</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-success make-flex">

            <!-- THIS IS MY CURRENT (NON-WORKING) SOLUTION: -->

            <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
              <p>feature afaa</p>
              <p>feature 2</p>
              <p>feature 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
              <p>feature 4</p>
              <p>feature 5</p>
              <p>feature 6</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- REMAINDER OF CODE FOR DISPLAY PURPOSES ONLY -->

      <!-- Package 2 -->
      <div class="col-md h-md-100 mx-md-4 my-md-0 my-4 bg-white p-3">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="mb-3 bg-success text-center">
            <p>Package 2</p>
            <p>$19.99</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-success">
            <p>features</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Package 3 -->
      <div class="col-md h-md-100 bg-white p-3">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="mb-3 bg-success text-center">
            <p>Package 3</p>
            <p>$9.99</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-success">
            <p>features</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just adding flex results in odd behavior. However, I found another solution which I'm about to post.

Comment: I think adding `d-flex` adds other properties, but I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: Instead of adding custom `make-flex` just use `row`.

Comment: @JakubMuda of course, however, I was only demonstrating that the parent needed to have `display: flex` for the children to behave correctly. `.row` adds other properties.  Simplest way to show was a custom class (I could have done inline too)

Answer (score 1):

I explored a suggestion offered by @disinfor that led to my figuring out a solution.

My solution is to add two properties to the parent div: `d-flex` and `flex-md-column`.

Just `d-flex` alone results in strange behavior. It's the addition of `flex-md-column` that appears to create the proper rendering output.

```
<div class="col-md h-100 bg-white p-3">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="mb-3 bg-success text-center">
              <p>Startup Package</p>
              <p>Best value for startups</p>
              <p>$19.99</p>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-md-column bg-success">
              <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                <p>feature 1</p>
                <p>feature 2</p>
                <p>feature 3</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
                <p>feature 4</p>
                <p>feature 5</p>
                <p>feature 6</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - You don't have a correct order of nesting your columns.

The order is as follows
`container` → `row` → `col` → `row` → `col` → and so on.

Solution? Just add `row` to `<div class="row bg-success">`

```
<div class="row bg-success">

    <!-- THIS IS MY CURRENT (NON-WORKING) SOLUTION: -->

    <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
```

SEE MORE: [DOCUMENTATION](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#nesting)

Comment: Interesting observation. I'll test this out when I have time.